# Java time: local date time without zone

Tags: java, java-time

I'm getting two outputs when I log this code:

```
private void meth(Date date) {
    LOG.info(
        date.toInstant()
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));

    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
        date.toInstant(),
        ZoneId.systemDefault()
    );

    LOG.info(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));

}
```

I'm getting these logs:

```
2019-04-01 13:13:32.195  INFO --- : 2019-01-01T01:00:00+01:00[Europe/Madrid]
2019-04-01 13:13:32.197  INFO --- : 2019-01-01T01:00:00
```

Has `ldt` lost its original time zone?

How could I care that?

Answer (score 4):

You are using a `LocalDateTime`, which does not contain a timezone - see [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

> A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.

You want to use a [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

LocalDateTime is a date-time without a time-zone:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html